# SQL group by two columns where order doesn't matter, keep other columns

Tags: sqlite, group-by

Suppose I have this table - t1:

```
col1|col2|col3|score
x   |y   |a   |1
y   |x   |b   |2
z   |w   |c   |4
w   |z   |d   |2
```

and I want to group by col1 and col2 in a way where it doesn't matter if the value comes from col1 or col2, so x|y and y|x are grouped together. The aggregating function can be e.g. AVG. And I also want to keep the information in col3, so I want to get the result:

```
col1|col2|col3|score
x   |y   |a   |1.5
y   |x   |b   |1.5
z   |w   |c   |3
w   |z   |d   |3
```

I was able to do it like this:

```
create table t2 as select min(col1,col2) as col1, max(col1,col2) as col2 , avg(score) as score from t1 group by min(col1, col2), max(col1, col2);
select * from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2) or (t1.col1 = t2.col2 and t1.col2 = t2.col1);
```

but:
a. I'm not sure it's correct and
b. It takes forever on real data (table with 300k rows) using SQLite.
Is there a simpler/faster way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `AVG()` window function:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
  avg(score) over (partition by min(col1, col2), max(col1, col2)) score
from t1 
order by col3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PXwvE2mdmQGgE9KMzevSX/3).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | score |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ----- |
| x    | y    | a    | 1.5   |
| y    | x    | b    | 1.5   |
| z    | w    | c    | 3     |
| w    | z    | d    | 3     |
```

Comment: This is such an elegant way to combine two columns where order doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `MIN`/`MAX` trick:

```
SELECT
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3,
    t2.score
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(col1, col2) AS col1, MAX(col1, col2) AS col2, AVG(score) AS score
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY MIN(col1, col2) AS col1, MAX(col1, col2)
) t2
    ON MIN(t1.col1, t1.col2) = t2.col1 AND
       MAX(t1.col1, t1.col2) = t2.col2;
```